# How to run multiple playbooks each with a survey?

Tags: ansible, cisco, ansible-tower

I have two playbooks in ansible tower that each have surveys.

```
---
- name: Provision Routers
  import_playbook: provision_evpn_routers.yml
  
- name: Provision Switches
  import_playbook: provision_evpn_switches.yml
```

When I execute this main playbook, the surveys are not prompted and I get errors since the variables (that would populate from the surveys) do not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In the job template, you can store variables and create the main survey. But, since Tower controls the input and stdout from playbook execution, you'll not be able to give any arguments or entries after job template starts.

You can create a workflow instead calling playbooks directly.
Check this out:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/workflow_templates.html#surveys